# Produtos do carrinho de compras duplicam

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou com um problema no carrinho de compras na questão do botão finalizar pedido. Quando finalizo o pedido ele deveria pegar todos os produtos. Até aí tudo bem, mas a questão que ele duplica sempre o último. No exemplo eu coloquei um produto com X-SALADA, e X-BACON. Ele simplesmente ignorou o primeiro e duplicou o último. Vejam o código e a imagem:

```
// SALVAR FINALIZAR O PEDIDO
$('#btn-finalizar-pedido').click(function (e)
{
    .preventDefault();

    (".item-tbody .produto").each(function (i, valor)

    var totalcarrinho = $('.total-carrinho').text();
    obj.idprodutocart = $(this).parent().find('.imagem-prod').attr('data-id-prod-carrinho');
    obj.nomeprodutocart = $(this).parent().find('.nomeprodutocart').text();
    obj.quantidadeprodutocart = $(this).parent().find('.quantidadeprodutocart').text();
    obj.precoprodutocart = $(this).parent().find('.valorprodutocart span').text();
    obj.imagemprodutocart = $(this).parent().find('.imagem-carrinho').attr('src');

    if (obj.quantidadeprodutocart == '0')
    {
        alert('A quantidade do produto não pode ser igual a zero');
        exit();
    }
    else
    {
        if (totalcarrinho == 'R$ 0,00')
        {
        //  alert('O seu carrinho está vazio');
        }
        else
        {
        arrayObj.push(obj);
        produtosArray = JSON.stringify(arrayObj);
        // array objeto e session storage do site
        sessionStorage.setItem('dadosproduto', produtosArray);
        essionStorage.setItem('valortotal',totalcarrinho);
        // vai para a página de carrinho de compras
        $(location).attr('href', 'carrinho.php');
        }

    }

    );

});
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: De onde vem o objeto obj que você usa na linha 7:`obj.idprodutocart = $(this).parent().find('.imagem-prod').attr('data-id-prod-carrinho');` ? Será que você não deveria limpar ele antes de usar?

Comment: Numa da últimas linhas, em `essionStorage.setItem('valortotal',totalcarrinho);` está faltando um "s" em "session".

Comment: Pior que já corrigi isso mas não bem este problema